# why this code dont work on firefox and internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox

hello i have developed this code

page1.php

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; url=page2.php">
```

--

page2.php

```
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];  
echo $referer;
$query = parse_url($referer, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query, $queryArr);
$id = $queryArr['id'];
echo '<br>';
echo $h;
```

so when i need to try the code i go to the link 
domain.com/page1.php?id=83

in chrome its shown

```
    domain.com/page.php?id=83
    83
```

and i firefox, internet explorer 
its shown nothing just a blank page i want to know how can i fix this code so its work on all browsers

Comment: Are you generating a doctype? an html declaration or anything else that is normally part of an actual web page?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should just use a php header redirect in page 1?

```
<?php header('Location: page2.php?id=83'); ?>
```

Comment: no becuase i have different domain page1.php is on one domain and page2.php is on other domain

Comment: You can put a domain in the `Location:` header.

Comment: The `'Location'` HTTP header should have an absolute URL as its value. So `http://mysite.com/path` for example. See the official specifications for the standard in [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30)